# Symfony 1.4 Path to modules

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

Following structure:

```
apps/backend/
apps/frontend/
             modules/
                    account/template/_menu.php
                    account/template/test.php
                    settings/template/indexSuccess.php
```

I do include _menu in test.php with the following code:

```
<?php slot('menu'); ?>
<?php include(dirname(__FILE__).'/_menu.php') ; ?>
<?php end_slot() ?>
```

How can I include the file _menu.php in indexSuccess.php?
Thanks!

Gunnar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `include_partial` from the indexSuccess.php template:

```
// indexSuccess.php
// Use the array container to pass values available in indexSuccess to your partial
<?php include_partial('menu', array(
    'foo' => $foo,
    'bar' => $bar 
)) ?>
```

You can read more about it in [Symfony API Docs](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/PartialHelper).

Comment: You don't need to, Symfony will look in one of two places, either in /apps/app_name/templates (global) or in /apps/app_name/modules/module_name/templates. So all you need to do is ensure your partial (indicated with a '_') is in one of these two locations.